# Drawing circles with increasing radius in C#

Tags: c#

I am using the below code to draw the circles(reading centres from a csv file) with increasing radius. The increase in radius is 5 units per circle.

```
namespace MATLAB_file
 {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
    string[] read;
    float th; 
    int c = 0;
    int r;

    public List<PointF> circleCoordinates = new List<PointF>();

    int rl;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen linePen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue);
        Graphics grphx = this.CreateGraphics();
        grphx.Clear(this.BackColor);

        foreach (PointF point in this.circleCoordinates)
        {
            Pen redPen1 = new Pen(Color.Red, 100);
            e.Graphics.DrawArc(Pens.Red, point.X, point.Y, 1, 1, 0, 120F);
        }
        linePen.Dispose();

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double xx, yy;

        int i;
        int n = 0;
        float[] centre1 = new float[1000];
        System.IO.StreamReader sr;
        sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("centers.txt", true);

        char[] seperators = { ',' };
        string data = sr.ReadLine();
        read = data.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
        rl = read.Length;
        int a1 = rl / 2;

        for (c = 0; c < rl; c++)
        {


            centre1[c] = float.Parse(read[c]);

        }

        while (r < 200)

        {
            for (i = 0; i < a1; i++)

            {
                while (th < 360)
                {
                    xx = r * Math.Cos(th) + centre1[2 * i] + 100;
                    xx1 = (float)xx;

                    yy = r * Math.Sin(th) + centre1[2 * i + 1] + 100;
                    yy1 = (float)yy;
                    this.circleCoordinates.Add(new PointF(xx1, yy1));
                    this.Invalidate();

                    th = th + .360F;
                }

                th = 0;

            }
            r = r + 5;
        }

        }
    }
```

}

The above code is displaying all the circles but I do not want all circles to be displayed on canvas, rather only one circle should show with gradual increase in radius
Please suggest how to delete the previous drawn circle on drawing new one. Is there any other way to do it, if my later use includes removal of certain section of circles based on "th" values?

Comment: FYI Visual Studio is an IDE and not a programming language.

Comment: The main issue is that to see an animation you will need e.g. a Timer. the Paint event otherwise is either not called or, as in your code, doesn't have time to display the intermediate circles. Using CreateGraphics is almost always wrong. Here too. Keep the circle/radius data in a class level variable, draw in the Paint, Invalidate in a Timer.Tick and all is well..

Answer (score 0):

If you move the `Clear` call within the `foreach` you will see only the last drawn circle, though this could be achieved with drawing only the `Last` `circleCoordinates` too.

```
    foreach (PointF point in this.circleCoordinates)
    {
        grphx.Clear(this.BackColor);
        Pen redPen1 = new Pen(Color.Red, 100);
        e.Graphics.DrawArc(Pens.Red, point.X, point.Y, 1, 1, 0, 120F);
    }
```

---

An alternative interpretation:

You want animation, which generates the `onPaint` events (by timer ticks or on user input) and you increase a counter to select the circle to draw.

For that, you will need a new member in your program, like `int Index;` and you could select the circle based on this, using something the following code snippet (assuming you always have at least 1 `circleCoordinates`, animation restarts after it finished):

```
PointF point = this.circleCoordinates[Index % circleCoordinates.Length];
```

or (last circle remain on the screen after the animation)

```
PointF point = this.circleCoordinates[Math.Min(Index, circleCoordinates.Length - 1)];
```

Comment: Looks like he wants an animation. You do mention Timer but only in passing. I think you could point out its importance a bit more. As it is it reads as if moving the clear would get closer to an animation, which it doesn't..

Comment: Thanks @TaW, I have updated the answer a bit, though I was not sure (s)he meant that, so I kept the first part too.

Comment: I want to read a book on different ways of generating animations in Visual studio, using C#. Please suggest.

Comment: thankyou @Gabor. I have a few fundamental queries, please clarify them. Now, I am using paint event to create the animation. Can you please suggest if using picture box is better. Also, I am able to draw animation of circles. Can you please tell , if using Timer will improve the results obtained i.e circles of increasing radius.

Comment: Also, I am using Windows Form and NOT WPF for my application as I know C# only. Please suggest, if WPF is better for animations purpose or Windows Form is good to go.

Comment: @ Taw, Please elaborate the use of Timer. I am unable to see the effect of it where I want to see the radius increasing each time for only as many circles as many centres are there.